# tmap_mode('view') is not plotting in interacrive mode in Jupyter-Notebook

Tags: r

When I am setting `tmap_mode('view')` for plotting in interactive mode, no plot appears in jupyter-notebook. I get this message:

> IOPub data rate exceeded. The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output to the client in order to avoid crashing it.

`tmap_mode("plot")` does show a plot however the background doesn't appear. I am using `tm_basemap(server = "OpenStreetMap")`

Any help would be appreciated